# Regression and Kuznets curve

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, gdp, regression, gini

The dependent variable, `Gini (C)` has the coefficient and probability value of $(38.934, 0.0000)$. The independent variables: `GDP`, `log(squared GDP)` and `Inflation` have the coefficients and probability values of $(-0.0003,0.8111)$,$(-0.1222,0.7111)$ and $(-0.0677,0.8111)$ respectively. What is the relationship between `GDP` and `log(squared GDP)`? Does the Kuznets curve holds in this model?

Aren't GDP and log (squared GDP) similar? How can I compare both of them to come up with a conclusion explaining what kind of relationship they have? Based on this question, what is the main factor I have to look for to estimate the Kuznets curve? I really don't know and I just put my answer as: There is a negative relationship...

---

This was an exam question and it is quite complicated for me, so I seek any means of help from this platform to explain this question. Note: I do not have the exact question with me, so the decimals are based on whatever I remember from the paper.

Comment: how come the dependent variable has a coefficient with probability value? In a regression you are regressing the dependent variable on independent variables $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_x2 +... + e$ the independent variables will have coefficient (betas) but the dependent variable doesn't. Can you please show us what sort of model you estimated because it does not seem to be regular regression

Comment: @1muflon1 The question was similar as above like what I saw on the paper, with an asterisk * below stating the (C) is the dependent variable, Gini. There was no indication of what kind of regression it was. My lecturer has only touched on basic linear and quadratic regression interpretation and Kuznets curve theory as of the day before my exam. So I assume it is about quadratic regression since it was asking for Kuznets.